# Huawei Map Kit API: The app ID does not have the service call permission

Tags: php, http-post, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-map-kit

I'm trying to access eg. `https://mapapi.cloud.huawei.com/mapApi/v1/routeService/*`, but only getting [`405/403`](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References/error-code-0000001050161430), while endpoints `elevation` and `mapService` are returning `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`.

I'm using an API key from an AgConnect project, but also tried with one from HMS Developer site. And also tried providing a bearer token, which lead to the same result, while it works for other APIs.

```
POST {"origin":{"lat":54.216608, "lng":-4.66529},"destination":{"lat":54.2166, "lng":-4.66552}}
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed {"returnCode": "403", "returnDesc": "REQUEST_DENIED"}
```

The documentation for return-code `403` reads:

> The app ID does not have the service call permission.
> Enable Map Kit in [AppGallery Connect](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/service/josp/agc/index.html).
> For details, please refer to [Enabling Services](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/agc-help-enabling-service-0000001146598793).

But Map Kit API is enabled and endpoints `elevation` and `mapService` do count towards the quota.
What's wrong with the `routeService` endpoint? Or is this service only available in Mainland China? Just wondering, because I'm requesting from `localhost` in Europe. Related code: [`Directions.php`](https://github.com/syslogic/php-hms/blob/master/src/MapKit/Directions/Directions.php). [`MapKitTest.php`](https://github.com/syslogic/php-hms/blob/master/tests/MapKitTest.php) needs an API key defined in `phpunit.xml` to reproduce the problem.

```
<env name="HUAWEI_MAPKIT_API_KEY" value=""/>
```

When I try with another project with Map Kit disabled, the calls to Elevation, Static Map and Map Tile API fail. It's only the `routeService` endpoint and these requests are nowhere being logged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same problem and solved it by activating Navi Kit in AppGallery Connect. Finally, don't forget to update your agconnect-services.json file

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms/huawei-navikit/), this appears reasonable; there's just no `agconnect-services.json`, but the access credentials should stay the same when enabling an API. I'll try that later.